# How to replace the letters in a lengthy sentence after a specific width

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress site. Check [here](http://beta.cpmfinancial.co.uk/) , in which in the footer area , I have listed latest posts. But in the case of posts having lengthy post titles, it is shown in 2 lines , I would like to display the post titles of a single post only in one line and would like to implement some dots ..... at the end . How can I do this ?

Comment: [mb_strimwidth](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php)

Comment: Why not use css ellipsis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are limiting the text to a single line, you can use CSS3 to accomplish this easily. You need a block-level element (in your case, this would be the `<li>` tags), set the maximum width you want the text to occupy using `width`, then set `overflow`, `white-space`, and `text-overflow` properties:

```
.title {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

If you need more than one line of text, unfortunately CSS does not have a mechanism for this. I've personally used [jquery dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

```
.truncate {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```